# Best Practices when using JSON to update DB

Tags: json, django, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

I am working on an API for my first web app, a scheduling system, with Django on the back end.

Shifts are sent to the front end in a single JSON object (`schedule`), that contains `shift` objects. This object can then be modified by the front end and sent back to have the server update the database according to any changes in the JSON object.

My question: is it better to use "marker" properties, such as `{... "delete": true...}` and `{... "new": true...}` within the `shift` objects to let the server know what has changed, or should the back end figure it out on its own by comparing the incoming data to existing data?

The first option seems to me to allow for fewer database queries, while the second option seems more robust (i.e. it does not depend on the front end to properly tag its changes).

Also, as this is my first attempt at web dev, any related recommendations or criticisms are encouraged.

Comment: on server side - delete everything from table, then insert new rows (from json file), thus you don't need to track changes neither on front nor back

Comment: @Lashane I considered that as well, but if there are, say, a few hundred `shift`s in the schedule wouldn't that be a huge waste if only one or two `shift`s have changed?

Comment: I think it depends on how much you trust who is using the api. Can you trust that the "markers" are going to be correct? If it is a third party that is using the api, then I personally would default to something more like your second approach. But then again, if it were me, I'd use the DRF (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to handle all my api generation.

Comment: I would make the frontend send only modified shift objects (where any of the fields have changed), and backend would simply update all fields for those objects. It usually doesn't matter performance wise if you update 1 field or 10 inside one record, but it matters if you update 1 record or 10. If your shift object contains tens of fields, then it would make sense to optimize it further by marking modified fields or sending only modified fields.

Comment: @serg the object being sent back could possibly contain hundreds of records. I'm thinking I'll have the server compare the incoming data to its existing data and only make updates to the db where necessary.

Comment: @TheBrewmaster I'm checking out DRF, it definitely sounds helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck. It's an awesome package (IMO) because it is so simple to start using, but can be so powerful too. There's lots of resources out there too,and I'd be happy to help if you want to send me a private message.